# The simple socle of a projective indecomposable module over a Frobenius algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $A$ be a finitely generated associated algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$, and $P$ a projective indecomposable $A$-module. It is a well-known result that $P/\text{rad}(P)$ is a simple module.

Suppose that $A$ is also a Frobenius algebra. On page 12 of Representations and Cohomology I (Garling, Fulton, and Walters), it states that $\text{soc}(P)$ is also simple; however it is not immediately obvious to me as to why this holds.

I suspect this has something to do with the *socle layer* (defined inductively by $\text{Soc}^0(M) :=0$, $\text{Soc}^{n}(M)/\text{Soc}^{n-1}$) and the *radical layer* (defined similarly) being related by $\text{Soc}^j(M) \supseteq \text{Rad}^{n-j}(M)$ for all $0 \leqslant j \leqslant n$; or possibly that any projective module is also injective, and vice versa, in this case.

I can't seem to get very far with the knowledge available to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every (finite dimensional) Frobenius algebra is self-injective, so if $P$ is indecomposable projective, then it is also indecomposable injective and so has simple socle.

There are some nice notes by Rolf Farnsteiner on this. Search for self-injective on this page:
https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/birep/activities/topics/index.php

Comment: Thank you very much!